# MYSQL - Update row when the date more than 1 year

Tags: mysql, datetime, leap-year

I am had a query could able to update the row if DateTimeAdded is 1 year or more. But i find out that it wouldn't work in leap year. Anyone have better suggestion?

```
 CREATE EVENT UpdateProduct
     ON SCHEDULE
       EVERY 1 DAY
         DO

 update `product`  set Label = "ClearStock"  where  datediff(now(),
 DateTimeAdded) >= 365
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify rows that have `DateTimeAdded` value over a year old, you could do something like this:

```
 ... WHERE DateTimeAdded < NOW() + INTERVAL -1 YEAR
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Demonstration:

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 0 HOUR AS `now`
     , DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 YEAR AS `year_ago`
     , t.DateTimeAdded
     , t.DateTimeAdded < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 YEAR AS `compare`
  FROM ( SELECT '2015-01-24 11:00:00' AS `DateTimeAdded`
          UNION ALL
         SELECT '2015-01-25 13:00:00'
          UNION ALL
         SELECT '2015-01-26 14:00:00'
       ) t
```

returns:

```
NOW                  year_ago    DateTimeAdded        compare  
-------------------  ----------  -------------------  -------
2016-01-25 22:11:56  2015-01-25  2015-01-24 11:00:00        1
2016-01-25 22:11:56  2015-01-25  2015-01-25 13:00:00        0
2016-01-25 22:11:56  2015-01-26  2015-01-26 14:00:00        0
```

Comment: What it is `INTERVAL -1 YEAR`? Why need + with that `DateTimeAdded < Now()`

Comment: `+ INTERVAL -1 YEAR` subtracts a year from the datetime value. This is comparing the value of `DateTimeAdded` with a datetime value (one year ago from right now.)  It's easy to test the expression in a SELECT statement. Compare the values returned for the two expressions:  `SELECT NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL -1 YEAR`.

Comment: It seems like only can work if it is exactly one year right? Coz i just want to compare the date without time.

Comment: If you need to subtract "exactly one year", then use **`+ INTERVAL -1 YEAR`**.  It's possible to do something different. e.g. if you want to subtract 13 months and then add 720 hours, then **`+ INTERVAL -13 MONTH + INTERVAL 720 HOUR`**

Comment: If you only want to compare the date portion, and ignore the time component, then you can wrap a datetime expression in the `DATE()` function.  For example,  **`DATE(NOW())`** will return the current date, with time time component lopped off, as if the time component was set to midnight.

Comment: I tried this `DATE(DateTimeAdded) < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 YEAR` but it not working..

Comment: "it not working" isn't very descriptive of the behavior you are observing. Is the statement throwing an error? Returning unexpected results? What result were you expecting? I recommend you test the expressions  by including them in the select list of a `SELECT` statement. What we don't know is the datatype of the `DateTimeAdded` column. (Is that a `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, or something other datatype?)

Comment: Any reason you don't use `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR` As opposed to `NOW() + INTERVAL -1 YEAR`? Just curious.

Comment: @miken32 For example, user add a new product at 1/1/2015 and the label is "New". After 1 year  1/1/2016 it will update the label "ClearStock".